# Coding a quiz in JAVASCRIPT that returns movies to watch on Netflix

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

I am trying to learn objects at the moment. So I have five different variables that are set to zero and will increment by 1 each time it is clicked on in the quiz. 
(I am creating a quiz to determine what movie or show you should watch on Neflix. )

```
var answer = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    c: 0,
    d: 0,
    e: 0
};


function selection (choice) {
    answer[choice]++;
    console.log(answer);
    console.log(choice);
};
```

However, my trouble is returning the object with the greatest amount, and once I do that then I return a movie name based on what object is returned. I tried to do two functions...

```
function game() {
    var biggest = 'a';
    for (var choice in answer)
        if(answer[choice] > answer[biggest]) {
            biggest = choice;
            console.log(biggest);
        }
    return biggest;
};
```

the function above is a lot more cleaner than the bottom one but doesn't have the movie titles.

```
function submitt() {
    const {a, b, c, d, e} = answer
    if (a===2) {return 'Hobbs and Shaw'}
    if(a===1 && b===1) {return 'Jumanji' }
    if(a===1 && c===1) {return 'The Invitation'}
    if(a===1 && d===1) {return 'Incredibles 2'}
    if(a===1 && e===1) {return 'Someone Great'}
    if(b===2) {return 'The Good Place'}
    if(b===1 && c===1) {return 'Black Mirror'}
    if(b===1 && d===1) {return 'Liv and Maddie'}
    if(b===1 && e==1) {return 'Jane the Virgin'}
};
```

My question is, how can i define an object in my if statement, because the error I get is "a is not defined". How do I define the objects?

Comment: In JS everything has scope.  ‘a’ inside object answer is not the same ‘a’ as in submitt()

Comment: in `submitt()` function, you didn't use `obj` where you wrote `for(obj in answer)`

Comment: @Antenaina how would I use an object? Do I replace obj with 'a'?

Comment: the loop is an iteration through the **keys** of the object `answer` so `obj` will be first `a` then `b` and so on. You can read the **value** with `answer[obj]` and it will be equivalent to, for example, `answer.a` in the first iteration. I suggest to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) about JS objects

Answer (score 0):

To answer the immediate question - you don't need the `for` loop in the body of the `submitt()` function because you don't need to iterate here, you need to go over various combinations of the key-value pairs in the `answer` map, which is done in the (admittedly unwieldy) `if` statement. You could either drop the `for` loop and refer to the elements by their proper full name, or you could use destructuring to assign the answers to the local variables and save yourself some typing.

With destructuring, your function would look like this:

```
function submitt() {
  const {a, b, c, d, e} = answers

  if (a === 2) { /* ... existing if logic goes here ... */ }
}
```

The bigger problem with this code though, is that the movie selection logic is hardcoded. A better approach would be to somehow encode the answers in such way that a unique combination of answers would produce a unique "key" - then you could simply put all the movie titles in a map and get rid of the huge "if" altogether. It is hard to suggest the best way of doing it though without knowing the quiz questions/answers and the logic behind it

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited the code but i was unsure of whether to just put one if statement for each one. And would the 'answer' be my var answer? Because i thought it was defined at the very beginning?

Comment: You are welcome. In your case, the "answer" is defined as a "global variable" (which is less than ideal by the way) and is "visible" to all the functions without additional declarations. If you were to re-declare "answer" in the function body, you would in fact create a new variable with the same name that would "shadow" the actual answers and break the logic.

Comment: Generally speaking, I think you should read up on the scopes because they are central to JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Declarations

This link has a nice overview of scopes and visibility, though a bit lengthy :)